# order by clause on status in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a sorting on a table to show the records with status having 3 first then status having 4 and then 1.

in current table this is the output

```
id    status
 1     3
 2     4
 3     4
 4     3
 5     1
```

now when i apply the query

```
select * from table order by model.status desc
```

the output is:

```
id    status
 2     4
 3     4
 1     3
 4     3
 5     1
```

what i want actually the below output. first with status 3 then with status 4 and then with status 1. How to achieve the below output

```
id    status
 1     3
 4     3
 2     4
 3     4
 5     1
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle or both?

Comment: Please format your question properly. HTML is limited, so try and not use it. You can use actual returns in the question text instead of `<br>`. You can also preview it while entering, right below the text area you're entering it into, in a WYSIWYG type fashion. Thanks.

Comment: Possible values in status columns are 1,3 and 4 only? Or other values can also be there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of a magic 9999999 number, you can use ~0, which represents the maximum possible value for big int... should be enough ;)

```
order by (case when status = 1 then ~0 else status end)
```

other solution, without any magic number

```
order by status = 1 , status
```

which will sort by a "boolean" (0 or 1 in DB) first, then by status

Comment: Raphael it actually worked thanks..:). I will accept this answer.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Just out of interest, in case you know, will the query sorting be able to use indexes when you order by a `CASE`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson to bo honest, no idea. I don't see why it would change anything, as long as we're working on an indexed field, but an explained query would be needed (and I ain't got any MySql server to test this).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) to do that easily on MySQL;

```
SELECT * 
FROM model
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 3, 4, 1);
```

[SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb001/3).

Comment: it says FIELD does not exist. I think it is a keyword in MYSQL rite?

Comment: @Java_NewBie It's actually a function that has existed since at least MySQL 5.0, which version are you using?

Comment: @Java_NewBie I seem to remember that 5.0 was a bit sensitive when it comes to spacing, try removing the space, ie, `ORDER BY FIELD(status, 3, 4, 1);`

Answer (score 3):

If [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) is not working for you (perhaps due to older version of MySql) then try this. It will work

```
SELECT * FROM model
ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 3 THEN 1  WHEN 4 THEN 2  WHEN 1 THEN 3
END, id
```

[**Check it working on this link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd54/6)

Answer (score 2):

```
$invoiceList = InvoicesModel::where('hotel_id', $hotel_id)
                        ->where('status', 'PENDING')
                        ->orWhere('status', 'COOKING_PROCESS')
                        ->orderBy(
                            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN status = "COOKING_PROCESS" 
                            THEN 1 WHEN status = "PENDING"
                            THEN 2 END)')
                        )->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use SQL [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY FIELD (status, 3, 4, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
 ORDER BY  CASE status WHEN 3 THEN 1
                 WHEN 4 THEN 2
                 WHEN 1 THEN 3
                 END, id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "[FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)" in order by clause if status values are 1,3 and 4 only.

```
select * from table order by FIELD( model.status 3,4,1)
```